# Linq Query: Join at 2nd level of Hierarchy

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I need to compare two objects of the same structure.

Each type contains a collection of other type.

ProcessA **->** ChildrenA (of links)

ProcessB **->** ChildrenB (of links)

How can I query using LINQ these two objects.
and say:

> what items of the ***collection childrenA*** of **ProcessA**, exist in
>   the *collection ChildrenB* of **ProcessB**.

Basically a join at a **2nd level** of this ***Hierarchy***.
I can't seem to be able to find a way to join them using Linq in **VB.NET**

Thank you in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you only want the children of processA that also exist in processB you don't need a join, you'd write something like this:

```
var Matches = ProcessA.ChildrenA.Where(a=>ProcessB.ChildrenB.Any(b=>b==a));
```

Update : for entity Framework (don't do this with linq to objects, would be very slow! this is converted to good SQL however)

```
var q = from a in ProcessA.ChildrenA
    from b in ProcessB.ChildrenB
    where a.Name == b.Name
    select new {a,b}
```

Comment: I am trying to determine what childrenA exist in ChildrenB collection. Using an Entity Framework Context and Linq. The "Join" condition would be by ChildrenA.Name = ChildrenB.Name

Comment: You should've specified it was for linq to entities (having no entity / sql tag it's assumed to be linq to objects), updating my answer

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll test it. I'm new to EF and Code first and Linq. by the way the entities are generated using Code first. I I'm struggling to include the children. When I say "ProcesA." there is no ChildrenA collection. So I'm figuring out the alternatives. I'll get back to you in a minute. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I can't seem to be able to do this ProcessA.ChildrenA, in my case would be context.ProcessA.ChildrenA. I also tried returning query = From context.ProcessA and can't seem to be able to access the Children, directly or through a query result in Linq to entities.

Comment: It says: ChildrenA is not a member of 'system.linq.iqueryable

Comment: Can't really help you without more info, you'd need to post your classes here (add them to your original post), ALL of the concerned classes (the model, the process class, the children property etc etc), or better yet zip up your project & put it on dropbox or similar if you're allowed to do that.